# Can't use a font in Kotlin Multiplatform

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-resources, kotlin-multiplatform, compose-multiplatform

Pretty simple; just created a Compose Multiplatform project from the wizard.

Went ahead and created the Theme; but I wanted to use the same font so I put `poppins.ttf` inside `commonMain/resources/font/`.

Then I declared the following in `commonMain` module:

```kotlin
expect val projectFontFamily: FontFamily
```

On the `commonDesktop` module I used:

```kotlin
actual val projectFontFamily: FontFamily = FontFamily(
  Font("font/poppins.ttf")
)
```

Great, that worked. Now on `commonAndroid`:

```kotlin
actual val projectFontFamily: FontFamily = FontFamily(
  Font(R.font.poppins)
)
```

For some reason the `R` class is not properly being generated and I cannot use `R.font.poppins`.

If I rename "resources" to "res" and shove the font into `res/font/` then it works. (But I just duplicated the font file).

How do I get around doing this?

Comment: Hello! I'm not too familiar with Compose Multiplatform, but walking through the repo, I've found this [doc](https://github.com/JetBrains/compose-jb/blob/master/tutorials/Native_distributions_and_local_execution/README.md#adding-files-to-packaged-application). It looks like one could override the Compose's default resources by using these variables and make them use the same `res` as the Android part.

Comment: You were on the right path. Yesteday night we ended up providing a fix for that [over here](https://github.com/NanoSpicer/KDrop/blob/master/common/build.gradle.kts)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It turns out it's rather a gradle issue and some inexperience with KMM.

Kotlin multiplatform projects by default (regardless of the platform) provide their resources in a folder called `resources` inside each module.

Problem is that the default folder for Android needs to be called `res`

So you can apply a fix either way:

Change `resources` folders to `res` and modify gradle accordingly *or* indicate in the Android project that the resource folder is not `res` but `resources`.

We ended up doing the latter in [our project](https://github.com/NanoSpicer/KDrop/blob/master/common/build.gradle.kts)

```kotlin
// build.gradle.kts
android {
  ...
  sourceSets["main"].res.srcDirs(
    "src/commonMain/resources",
    "src/androidMain/resources"
  )
  ...
}
```